# Code gives error for InputBox and I dont know why

Tags: delphi

I have an array of type string, and when I call the `InputBox` function it gives me an error, I don't know why. It's really annoying even though the code is the exact same from my textbook.

literally my code:

```
var
  arrNames: array[1..10] of string;
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 10 do
    arrNames := inputbox('Enter name here');
```

I understand this is probably something meaningless and simple, but please help me out.

I've tried `StrToInt` and `IntToStr`, even though they have no use there. I have also tried putting random stuff there. It just doesn't work... please help.

Comment: What error are you getting?  What debugging have you tried?  Have you looked at the documentation for both the InputBox and the assignment of arrays?

Answer (score 1):

[`InputBox()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs.InputBox) has more than 1 parameter that you are required to pass in.

Also, it returns a `single` string, not an array of strings, so your loop needs to index into the array for each `string` that is returned.

Try this instead:

```pascal
var
  arrNames: array[1..10] of string;
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 10 do
    arrNames[i] := InputBox('Caption Here', 'Enter name here', '');
            ^^^
```

Alternatively, you can prompt the user for multiple strings at one time by using [`InputQuery()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs.InputQuery) instead, eg:

```pascal
var
  arrPrompts: array[1..10] of string;
  arrNames: array[1..10] of string;
begin
  for i := 1 to 10 do
    arrPrompts[i] := 'Enter name here';
  InputQuery('Caption Here', arrPrompts, arrNames, nil);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would have read [InputBox](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Dialogs.InputBox) documentation you would have seen that `InputBox` function expects three input parameters while you have provided only one.

And I strongly doubt your text book is calling `InputBox` with only one parameter since `InputBox` has always been expecting three input parameters.

Another problem here is that you are not trying to set the `InputBox` result to specific array item but to as whole array variable.

The correct way would be like so:

```
arrNames[i]:= inputbox('Enter name','Please enter name here','');
```

Notice that `arrNames` is followed with square brackets surrounding `i`. This controls to which array element you are setting the result of `InputBox` function.

Also notice that I used three parameters when calling input box. First parameter is a string that will be shown as caption of the `inputBox`. Second parameter is the text within the input box. And as third parameter I passed an empty string which is a default value already shown in `InputBox`.